# how to get current employees status,resigned status,newly joined status in particular period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle11g

I have employee master table in this table have empcode,empname,joindate,resigndate  but not mention any date for entry in master.
How to get current employees,no of employees resigned,no of employees joined in particular date periods

for ex:

```
current employees  -200
resigned employees -25
joined employees   -10
current status     -200+10=210-25=185
```

this every i wanted in table format

Comment: Variations of `COUNT( CASE WHEN joindate BETWEEN ... )`

Comment: Show what you have tried and we can help you from there, but SO is not a code writing service. Also decide if you're using Oracle or SQL Server. Those are completely different products.

Comment: Where is your schema? How do we know how they relate to each other?And your question is too specific that will not help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a calendar table or date dimension, query, view... etc, this becomes much simpler.

```
/* example Calendar, just Months */
create table dbo.Calendar(
    MonthStart date primary key
  , MonthEnd   date
);

declare @FromDate date = '20000101';
declare @ThruDate date = '20301201';

with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, d as (
  select DateValue=convert(date,dateadd(month
      , row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1, @fromdate))
    from         n as deka
      cross join n as hecto
      cross join n as kilo
)
insert into dbo.Calendar
  select top (datediff(month, @FromDate, @ThruDate)+1)
      MonthStart    = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateValue), 0)
    , MonthEnd      = dateadd(day,-1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateValue)+1, 0))
    from d
    order by DateValue;
```

---

Query using a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and then `sum(case when.. 1 else 0 end)`

```
;with cte as (
select
    c.MonthStart
  , c.MonthEnd
  , e.EmpCode
  , e.JoinDate
  , e.ResignDate
from dbo.Calendar as c
  inner join dbo.EmpMaster as e
    on  c.MonthEnd   >= e.JoinDate
    and c.MonthStart <= e.ResignDate
)
select
    MonthStart
  , MonthEnd
  , CurrentEmployees = sum(
          case when JoinDate   <  MonthStart
               then 1 else 0 end )
  , Joined           = sum(
          case when JoinDate   >= MonthStart and JoinDate   <= MonthEnd
               then 1 else 0 end)
  , Resigned         = sum(
          case when ResignDate >= MonthStart and ResignDate <= MonthEnd
               then 1 else 0 end)
  , CurrentStatus    = sum(
          case when ResignDate > MonthEnd
               then 1 else 0 end)
from cte
group by
    cte.MonthStart
  , cte.MonthEnd
order by cte.MonthStart;
```

without the cte, and using `count(case when ... then column else null end)` instead:

```
select
    MonthStart
  , MonthEnd
  , CurrentEmployees = count (
      case when JoinDate   <  MonthStart
           then EmpCode else null end )
  , Joined           = count (
      case when JoinDate   >= MonthStart and JoinDate   <= MonthEnd
           then EmpCode else null end )
  , Resigned         = count (
      case when ResignDate >= MonthStart and ResignDate <= MonthEnd
           then EmpCode else null end )
  , CurrentStatus    = count (
      case when ResignDate > MonthEnd
           then EmpCode else null end )
from (
    select
    c.MonthStart
  , c.MonthEnd
  , e.EmpCode
  , e.JoinDate
  , e.ResignDate
from dbo.Calendar as c
  inner join dbo.EmpMaster as e
    on  c.MonthEnd   >= e.JoinDate
    and c.MonthStart <= e.ResignDate
    ) as cte
group by cte.MonthStart, cte.MonthEnd
order by cte.MonthStart
```

Each returns the same results:  http://rextester.com/AEZTL76069

```
+------------+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| MonthStart |  MonthEnd  | CurrentEmployees | Joined | Resigned | CurrentStatus |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-01-31 |                0 |      3 |        0 |             3 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-02-28 |                3 |      1 |        0 |             4 |
| 2010-03-01 | 2010-03-31 |                4 |      2 |        0 |             6 |
| 2010-04-01 | 2010-04-30 |                6 |      1 |        0 |             7 |
| 2010-05-01 | 2010-05-31 |                7 |      2 |        0 |             9 |
| 2010-06-01 | 2010-06-30 |                9 |      1 |        0 |            10 |
| 2010-07-01 | 2010-07-31 |               10 |      1 |        0 |            11 |
| 2010-08-01 | 2010-08-31 |               11 |      2 |        0 |            13 |
| 2010-09-01 | 2010-09-30 |               13 |      6 |        0 |            19 |
| 2010-10-01 | 2010-10-31 |               19 |      2 |        0 |            21 |
| 2010-11-01 | 2010-11-30 |               21 |      1 |        0 |            22 |
| 2010-12-01 | 2010-12-31 |               22 |      0 |        0 |            22 |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------+----------+---------------+
```